# How to retrieve time zone choices on Windows Mobile for PDA

Tags: windows-mobile, timezone

Is there a way to retrieve the time zone choices in Windows Mobile in order to display them in a GUI? It would be much better not to have to show every 15 minutes just to be
able to display GMT+5:45 for Kathmandu.

Answer (score 1):

As per [MSDN:City List and Time Zone Data Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa458853.aspx),

> You can add or remove content to these
>   files. You can redistribute these
>   files as is or repackage this data by
>   including it in source code, a
>   database, or another format. You are
>   permitted to use excerpts of this data
>   rather than the entire data set.

```
Note   Microsoft bears no responsibility for the content or
usage of these files. Certain locales have specific legal requirements with
regard to providing data of this type; ensure you are in compliance with such
regulations.
```

> If you use the city data
>   provided or if you use any type of
>   geographical information from any
>   source, you are encouraged to provide
>   a way for users to edit, add, and
>   delete information.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Mobile stores timezone info in a [file called Timezones.csv](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa458853.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Timezones.csv & CityList.csv files are provided in the \Resource folder of the Windows Mobile SDK!

You could modify the list and decide the ones which you want to show to the user.